# How to pass output of one graph as input to another graph in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to do transfer learning with INCEPTION_V4 model as feature extractor 
and downloaded the code and checkpoint file from 
[GitHub repository of Tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim#pre-trained-models)

Then I added my own layer for classification in 5 classes. But during model restore using tf.train.Saver, it showing error that it can not find variable values for my layer that I added.

To solve this, I created two separate graphs, one for loading pre-trained model and one for my classification layers. But I can't pass output of one graph as input to the second graph. 
Can you suggest any other way to do transfer learning or solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy solution is to just construct the inception model (without your layers), then create the saver and use it for restore, and only then create your layers.

There are more complex solutions (you can pass the `var_list` parameter of `tf.Saver` with the list of all variables you want to restore, and initialize that to be the list of all the inception variables), but this one should be straightforward, and I do it with my transfer learning models.

Comment: Can you share me some of your codes/works of transfer learning. Plz

Comment: Or any online article, github repository that you find helpful